# How to replace string in files using asterisk in search form

Tags: text-processing, sed

In my log files (*.log) I want to replace all occurrence of:

```
"INFO=*",
```

to

```
"INFO=*;;;",
```

where `*` could be anything.

So, for example, `"INFO=1234",S` -> `"INFO=1234;;;",S` Is there a way how to do it with sed ?

Answer (score 2):

Use capturing parentheses to remember the changing part in the string:

```
sed -i~ 's/\("INFO=[^"]*\)",/\1;;;",/' *.log
```

You might need to add a `g` at the end if more than one INFO occurs per line.

This won't work if * contains double quotes.

Comment: variant `'s/"INFO=[^"]*/&;;;/'`